# Modify dtb after starting kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I currently use MIPI-DSI interface to connect a screen, when I modify its parameters (eg, hsync, vsync) in DTS, it works fine. Now my question is, can I drive two different screens (they have different parameters) through one MIPI-DSI interface.

What I want to do is: set a default screen parameter in DTS, when the system starts, the default screen can be displayed normally. If the user needs to switch screens, I dynamically modify the DTB screen configuration parameters in Linux to switch to another screen.

What I understand is that the dtb is already loaded during the bootloader stage, so not sure if it is still possible to modify it when the system is already booted into the kernel. If you have any experience or suggestions in this regard, I hope and thank you for your comments.

Comment: The DT blob is simply HW & board configuration information passed to the kernel and its drivers. If you "*modified*" the DT blob at runtime, there is no mechanism to get  the kernel to reprocess this info. You're looking at your problem the wrong way. You need to study how the driver uses the properties read from the DT blob, i.e. what runtime variables are being initialized? One method of interacting with an executing driver is **sysfs**.

Comment: @sawdust, there is (okay, limited). It's called DT overlays.